# Is there a way to compute an Origin-Destination Matrix with multiple start point attributes?

Tags: pyqgis, vector, origin-destination

[QGIS 3.16] I am looking to compute an origin-destination matrix. However, from the starting point layer, I need to have multiple attributes within the matrix, opposed to the 1 linking attribute. Is this type of computation possible? I am not familiar with the log-side of coding the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to circumvent my problem - joining the layers I needed works wonderfully.